# RegEx.Escape ignoring parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

When using `RegEx.Escape` is it possible to ignore the parenthesis used for grouping/capturing?

```
RegEx.Escape("profile.php?user_id=([0-9]+)");
```

Currently it will escape the `([0-9]+)` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can but since this is the actual part of the regex that does the matching and doesn't need escaping, you can use:

```
string regex = Regex.Escape("profile.php?user_id=") + "([0-9]+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not quite possible, unless you split it >>

```
string s = Regex.Escape("profile.php?user_id=") + "([0-9]+)";
```